# Webpack error stack not showing in sourcemap file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

Im playing around with a `react` app and introduced webpack. the console error stack refers to `react-dom.production.min.js` a huge minified file rather than to the specific file with the undefined variable. The separate files were mapped but error stacks do not refer to specific file with the error.

**Error Stack**

```
ReferenceError: omak is not defined
Stack trace:
render@webpack-internal:///10:124:1
l@webpack-internal:///17:131:336
beginWork@webpack-internal:///17:138:287
e@webpack-internal:///17:176:105
f@webpack-internal:///17:176:379
G@webpack-internal:///17:182:329
x@webpack-internal:///17:181:378
n@webpack-internal:///17:181:221
B@webpack-internal:///17:180:117
v@webpack-internal:///17:179:51
b@webpack-internal:///17:190:302
updateContainer@webpack-internal:///17:191:389
tg.prototype.render@webpack-internal:///17:228:366
Eg/<@webpack-internal:///17:242:473
unbatchedUpdates@webpack-internal:///17:188:42
Eg@webpack-internal:///17:242:392
render@webpack-internal:///17:244:189
@webpack-internal:///20:19:1
@http://127.0.0.1:8080/bundle.js:217:1
__webpack_require__@http://127.0.0.1:8080/bundle.js:20:12
@http://127.0.0.1:8080/bundle.js:69:18
@http://127.0.0.1:8080/bundle.js:1:11
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
//const BabiliPlugin = require('babili-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
    }]
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map'
}
```

**Package.json**

```
 {
      "scripts": {
        "serve": "live-server public/",
        "build": "webpack --watch",
        "build-babel": "babel src/app.js --out-file=public/scripts/app.js --preset=env,react --watch"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
        "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-env": "1.5.2",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "babili-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.2",
        "live-server": "^1.2.0",
        "react": "^16.3.2",
        "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
        "validator": "^10.2.0",
        "webpack": "^4.8.3"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "webpack-cli": "^2.1.3"
      }
    }
```

**firebug sources**

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjUpz.png)